# Website images work locally on Minikube but not remotely on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a website that I recently wrote a deployment for using kubernetes. When deploying it on my local machine with minikube and viewing it with `minikube service srv-website` everything works fine. However, after deploying on GKE and exposing it via an Ingress the images do not load. Hovering over an image path in Insepct Element says "Could not load the image".

I've tried changing the paths to the images but that hasn't fixed the problem.

`<img src="./Images/A.png" class="img">`

`<img src="Images/A.png" class="img">`

`<img src="/usr/share/nginx/html/Images/A.png" class="img">`

The first two work locally, not the third with an absolute container path. None of them work on GKE even though both are running the same image.

Here is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cfg-website
data:
  custom.nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }

      error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
      }

      error_page 401 /401.html;
        location = /401.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
      }

      # gzip compression
      gzip_vary on;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_comp_level 6;
      gzip_buffers 16 8k;
      gzip_http_version 1.1;
      gzip_min_length 256;
      gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
      # gzip compression

    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dep-website
  labels:
    app: website
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: website
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: website
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-conf
        configMap:
          name: cfg-website
      containers:
      - name: cnt-website
        image: link/to/registry
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-conf
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          readOnly: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: srv-website
  labels:
    app: website
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: website
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
```

My ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: website-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: website-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: srv-website
          servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with my website's image paths, but with the ingress. The ingress was only mapping the path '/' to my website meaning links to images did not work. By chagning the ingress path to '/*' it was fixed as it now allowed for paths beyond '/' to exist on the website.

New Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: website-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: website-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: srv-website
          servicePort: 8080
```